# Trigger Lambda Periodically As Long as Webpage is Open

Tags: aws-lambda

I am developing a serverless web app in AWS that presents data from a DynamoDB. It's an Angular webapp, with an API Gateway backed by a Python Lambda function as a backend. I have another, separate Lambda function that updates the DynamoDB with fresh data. I would like to have that function run and update the DB once per minute or so, but only if someone is actively viewing the web page. It's a unique situation where it's important that the data on the page is up to date when it's open, but it could go days without being opened (it's a status dashboard for major incidents, so isn't used when everything is working). Is there a way to do this? The webpage auto-refreshes once per minute and hits the backend Lambda each time if that helps, but if multiple people have the page open I don't want redundant executions of the update function. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I suppose, but between being billed for Lambda execution, DB access, and API access on the other end of the update function, it would be nice to just have a global update once per minute or so, especially since the frontend auto-refreshes. Your solution is what I'll go with if what I am aiming for isn't possible.

Comment: A WebSocket-based solution, perhaps, so you can enumerate the connected clients.

Comment: "I would like to have that function run and update the DB once per minute or so, but only if someone is actively viewing the web page" when users first go to the webpage, do you want the data to already be available to them or do you want them to see data from whenever they stopped looking at the last incident?  "A WebSocket-based solution, perhaps" Take a look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-websocket-api-overview.html APIG has support for websockets and it looks pretty cool

Comment: " I don't want redundant executions of the update function"" ... "it would be nice to just have a global update once per minute or so" This sounds like the job of caching.  Run the function once a minute (when necessary), then put the results in S3.  Have the frontend poll that data (or just refresh, whatever).    If you want users to have updated information when they first visit a page, you'll have to have some way of knowing how old it is and triggering the lambda and telling the client when the new data is ready - websockets could help with that